# creating new object error JAVA android

Tags: java, android, class, object

I was planning to have a method that create a new object so I can renew the method everytime I call it

here is the code:

```
public class CollectedData {
     List<BusSearchOuterDataResults> busData = new ArrayList<BusSearchOuterDataResults>();
     public BusSearchOuterDataResults outerData;
     public void createNewOuterDataObject(){
         outerData = new BusSearchOuterDataResults();
         this.outerData = outerData;
     }
     public void createNewInnerDataObject(){
         outerData.createNewInnerDataObject();
     }
     public void addAllCollectedData(){
         busData.add(outerData);
     }
     public List<BusSearchOuterDataResults> getBusData(){
         return busData;
     }
}
```

Why is that when I call the createNewOuterDataObject method it wont let me create a new one is it because I call already the class obj of createNewOuterDataObject with out any Initialization?

```
public class BusSearchOuterDataResults {
List<BusSearchInnerDataResults> innerData = new ArrayList<BusSearchInnerDataResults>();

private String routeNo;
private String routeLabel;
private String direction;
public BusSearchInnerDataResults innerDataOBJ = new BusSearchInnerDataResults();

public BusSearchOuterDataResults(String routeNo, String routeLabel, String direction){
    this.routeNo = routeNo;
    this.routeLabel = routeLabel;
    this.direction = direction;
}

public BusSearchOuterDataResults(){

}

public void createNewInnerDataObject(){
    BusSearchInnerDataResults innerDataOBJ = new BusSearchInnerDataResults();
    this.innerDataOBJ = innerDataOBJ;
}
public void addAllCollectedData(){
    innerData.add(new BusSearchInnerDataResults());
}

public void setRouteNo(String routeNo){
    this.routeNo = routeNo;
}
public void setRouteLabel(String routeLabel){
    this.routeLabel = routeLabel;
}
public void setDirection(String direction){
    this.direction = direction;
}
public String getrouteNo(){
    return routeNo;
}
public String getrouteLabel(){
    return routeLabel;
}
public String getdirection(){
    return direction;
}
public List<BusSearchInnerDataResults> getData(){
    return innerData;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _it won't let you create a new one_?

Comment: well in my ADT eclipse I put some like this                Lod.d("INITIALIZING", "WAIT");             dc.createNewInnerDataObject();                           Lod.d("SUCCESS", "SUCESS"); BUT the SUCCESS log never showup after the initialization

Comment: What does that even mean...?

Comment: you should filter the logcat to error logs and show us the error stack , what exception is being thrown ?

Comment: We'll need to see the code in BusSearchOuterDataResults's constructor.  It looks like this is failing in some way, but it isn't apparent why from what you've posted so far.

Comment: Where is the BusSearchOuterDataResults  class,post the code

Comment: Hold on -- is it createNewOuterDataObject or createNewInnerDataObject that's failing?  In the problem description you say the former, but in your comment above it sounds like the latter is the issue.

Comment: @Jules Actually its both of them

Comment: Now we need the BusSearchInnerDataResults class... Or post the error that throws

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect :

```
public void createNewOuterDataObject(){
   outerData = new BusSearchOuterDataResults(); // here you are initializing your field
   this.outerData = outerData; // but here ? what is this line for ? 
}
```

the second line does nothing, its like doing

```
int x = 0 ;
 x=x;
```

Comment: True, but it isn't going to throw any Exceptions or cause any other problems.

Comment: Don't explain it to me. Add it to your answer. Explain why that's incorrect, or rather why it's probably not what OP needs.

Comment: @Tanis you can't cram your code with useless lines and expect it to work properly, you've got to write a clean understandable code and then try to debug it in case it throws exceptions